# Convert xml to idml

Tags: xml, perl, idml

I want convert to idml from xml

XML File:

```
<XLSE>
<table>
<tgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Sampe</td>
<td>Sampe</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Sampe</td>
<td>Sampe</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td>Sampe</td>
<td>Sampe</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</tgroup>
</table>
</XLSE>
```

I import in indesign this file, i got xml struture in idml,

1. how to get table format in story file without change in xml structure
2. how will get same input tag during xml file export in indesign

please give with sample

Comment: Can you show expected output for the given input for us not familiar with idml?

Comment: I got every column tag as <cell> tag but i can't get during xml export

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the given input?

Answer (score 1):

Say you want a 2x2 Table in an IDML file, the hierarchy would look something like = Story -> ParagraphStyleRange -> Table

A minimal Table element looks like this -

```
<Table Self="u126i190" ColumnCount="2" BodyRowCount="2" FooterRowCount="0" HeaderRowCount="0">     
    <Row Self="u126i190Row0"  Name="0"/> 
    <Row Self="u126i190Row1"  Name="1"/> 
    <Column Self="u126i190Column0" Name="0" SingleColumnWidth="47.760000000000005"/> 
    <Column Self="u126i190Column1" Name="1" SingleColumnWidth="47.760000000000005"/>
    <Cell Self="u126i190i5" Name="0:0" ColumnSpan="1" RowSpan="1"> 
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/$ID/NormalParagraphStyle">             
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]"/> 
                <Content>Row 1 Column 1</Content>
           </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
    </Cell>
    <Cell Name="1:0"> .... </Cell>
    <Cell Name="0:1"> .... </Cell>
    <Cell Name="1:1"> .... </Cell>
</Table>
```

The value of the Name attribute for a cell is = ColumnName:RowName.